# Missing bold and italic font in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, fontspec

Please see this MWE given below which tries to produce normal, bold and italic text in [Bengali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bengali_language).

```
\documentclass{article}

% For a bilingual document
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

% Times New Roman used for English
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}

% Bengali
\setotherlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{SolaimanLipi}
\newfontfamily\bengalifontbf[Script=Bengali]{SolaimanLipi}
\newfontfamily\bengalifonttt[Script=Bengali]{SolaimanLipi}
\newfontfamily\bengalifontsf[Script=Bengali]{SolaimanLipi}

\begin{document}

\begin{bengali}
  বাংলা ভাষা

  \textbf{বাংলা ভাষা}

  \textit{বাংলা ভাষা}

\end{bengali}

\end{document}
```

When compiled, the second and third text appear in normal font, with the following log message:

> ```
> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/SolaimanLipi(0)/bx/n' undefined
> (Font)              using `EU1/SolaimanLipi(0)/m/n' instead on input line 24.
>
>
> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/SolaimanLipi(0)/m/it' undefined
> (Font)              using `EU1/SolaimanLipi(0)/m/n' instead on input line 26.
> ```

However, the same font ([SolaimanLipi](https://www.omicronlab.com/download/fonts/SolaimanLipi_20-04-07.ttf)) can be used in other applications, e.g. LibreOffice to get the same effect.

[image]

What is it I could be doing wrong?

**EDIT**

***LibreOffice is using the same font***

[image]

***There is no other SolaimanLipi font in my machine***

Command

> sudo find / -name SolaimanLipi* -print

gives,

> /home/masroor/.local/share/fonts/SolaimanLipi_20-04-07.ttf

Comment: I downloaded the font from the link you provided and opened it in FontBook (a MacOS app). According to FontBook, the only weight provided is 'normal' -- no 'bold'. Is there maybe another version of the font somewhere that provides both normal and bold weights?

Comment: @Mico There is no other SolaimanLipi font in my machine. Please see my edit. But your observation regarding the font file is correct, the font viewer in Linux says that it has only normal font. However, the same font can be used in web browsers to view normal as well as bold and italic texts.

Comment: Sometimes applications like LO fake the bold effect for fonts that do not have this weight. Maybe you want to have a look at the according `fontspec` feature.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could work with the faking of bold fonts as many WYSIWYG editors are using this too.

In the following code I've added the `AutoFakeBold=4.0` font option. Just adjust the number to adjust the weight (the higher the bolder).

*Edit:* If you also want to fake italics/slanted font try using `AutoFakeSlant=0.4` where the number also indicates the strength of the slant.

[image: bengali faked bold and slanted]

```
\documentclass{article}

% For a bilingual document
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

% Times New Roman used for English
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}

% Bengali
\setotherlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{SolaimanLipi.ttf}
\newfontfamily\bengalifontbf[Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{SolaimanLipi.ttf}
\newfontfamily\bengalifonttt[Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{SolaimanLipi.ttf}
\newfontfamily\bengalifontsf[Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{SolaimanLipi.ttf}

\begin{document}

\begin{bengali}
  বাংলা ভাষা

  \textbf{বাংলা ভাষা}

  \textit{বাংলা ভাষা}

\end{bengali}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A nice solution.

Comment: @Masroor By far not, because it still only *fakes* the effects of bold and italic, but it's working (and without right font there's no real alternative).

Comment: Is there a way we can fake `tt` font as well? I am referring to the line, `\newfontfamily\bengalifonttt[Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{SolaimanLipi.ttf}`, which I think does not have any effect at all except using normal font for `tt`.

Comment: @Masroor Unfortunately not. And googling around I found no way to make a proportional font mono-spaced. That would be a great new question.

Comment: @TeXnician I tried `AutoFakeBold` with another font. I get the **`Bold`** effect. But the weight of the font remains unchanged when I change the number. What could be the reason. I tried with `Tiro Kannada` font

Comment: @VrajarajaGovindaDas I can't say without seeing the code. Best make a MWE and post a new question.